# bash script control spawned processes

Tags: bash, unix, process

I'm using a script like this to control a very long running processes's stdin and stdout externally:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch process.stdin
tail -fn0 process.stdin | my_process > process.stdout
```

This works fine, except when my_process exits the tail process doesn't exit. Is there a way I can get the tail to quit when my_process exits?

Alternatively is there a better way of setting this up?

Comment: From `man tail`: `--pid=PID  with -f, terminate after process ID, PID dies`. If you know the pid...?

Comment: How could I get the pid of my_process though but still be able to pipe to it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried with `--pid=$$` and `exec my_process`, but didn't have much success.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what my_process do, is it a script? it depends but may be creating a named pipe can make it simpler.

Comment: You want to follow the PID of the process which is *writing* to `process.stdin`.

Comment: You're tagging this with bash, but your script is run with sh.  Do you have access to a full bash?

Answer (score 1):

You actually formulate here: keep on (-f) displaying the last zero lines (-n0) of this ever growing file and shove it down my_process's throat.
Although my_process did exit it seems as if the -f flag prevents tail from exiting.

To end things nicely and surely in an uncomplicated way you could try to terminate tail from within it's child my_program on exit: `kill -SIGTERM $PPID`

or even in a very neat way:  `trap "kill -SIGTERM $PPID" EXIT`

if my_process is not a bash shell script, try this:

`tail -f process.stdin | ( my_process > process.stdout ; kill -SIGTERM $PPID )`

I persume that you are trying to pipe from a logfile. You could alternatively hookup the execution of my_process to rsyslog or use inotifywait.